# Looping Anchor tags to call to later when changing class or background

Tags: jquery, loops, anchor

I'm having a problem getting my anchors to behave like I want.  What I'm trying to do is take a variable I created: `

```
                         var color = $('a').text();`
```

The 'color' is taking the text in my anchors (just colors like blue, green, silver, white, black) and returning so that i can use them later in my code.

What ends up happening is when i'm using webdeveloper is i'm seeing the code as if were all one word.  so if i wanted to make a class with each one the class ends up looking like this:

`body class="blackwhiteredbluegreenyellowpurplebrownorangepink"`

when i want it to be separate body classes like 
body class="black" and then i can click white anchor to change the body class again to `"body class="white"`

I have tried putting in another variable and adding a count++ along with a jquery for loop and I was unsucessful in getting it to work.

I have the code working if i hand code each situation but that's a lot of work and cannot figure out the shorthand version

Comment: Oh and by the way I don't need to ADD any additional css like .css();  It's already in the css folder just waiting to be called on with the color anchor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jquery selector is returning an array of elements that are anchor links, so you're retrieving all the anchor links on the page and it's concatenating the text.

You could create an array of colors and fill it like so:

```
<a>black</a>
<a>green</a>
<a>red</a>
<a>blue</a>

var colors = [];
$('a').each(function(){
    colors.push($(this).text());    
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much this worked like a charm!!! the only thing i did differently was $('#id li').click(function() {
     $('body').removeClass();
     $('body').addClass($(this).text);
});
Added it into my anonymous function and now it's perfect! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

you have multiple a-tags on your page so you have to loop through them on by one... jquery concatenates the text so that's why you have one long string.

http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/nF6dM/

```
$('a').each(function (){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can use :

```
var colors = [];
$('a').text(function(index,value){
    colors.push(value);
});
```